# How can I bookmark a spot inside a UITextView?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a large amount of text in a UITextView. I want to let the user press a button and save the line that is displayed at the top of the view. Then when the same button is pressed it jumps to that exact line when the app is opened at a later time. Just like a physical bookmark.

How can I determine where the text is, or scrolling is?
How can I auto scroll to that position later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITextView` is a subclass of [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView), so you can use the `UIScrollView` messages [`contentOffset`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset) and [`setContentOffset:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset:animated:) to get and set the scrolling offset respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe how easy that was...

```
//grab current spot of scrollbar, usage: p.x & p.y as integers
CGPoint p = myText.contentOffset;

//scroll myText to a particular point
[myText setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
```